# Python 4D plot using matplotlib- confusion in reading and plotting the array

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have a list like below -

```
array1 = [[1,2,3,0.56],[12,5,30,0.23],[10,12,17,89.65]]
```

This represents co-ordinates- [[x1,y1,z1,c1],[x2,y2,z2,c2],[x3,y3,z3,c3]].
I used 4D plot with 4th dimension[c1,c2,c3] being the color. I am stuck at plotting. I would like to have a color for c1 at co-ordinates [x1,y1,z1] and similarly to other co-ordinates.

I used the below methods -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

1) for p in range(len(array1)-1):
         x = np.append([array1[p][0]], array1[p+1][0])
         y = np.append([array1[p][1]], array1[p+1][1])
         z = np.append([array1[p][2]], array1[p+1][2])
         c = np.append([array1[p][3]], array1[p+1][3])
   fig = plt.figure()
   ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
   ax.scatter(x,y,z,c=c,cmap = cmap)
   plt.show()
```

The problem in method 1 is, its not plotting all the elements of the list. I guess there is a mistake in executing append. I am not getting any errors but its just not plotting every data.

```
2) fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

    for p in range(len(array1)-1):
        ax.scatter(array1[p][0],array1[p][1],array1[p][2],array1[p][3],cmap = 
         cmap)
    plt.show()
```

So in method 2, I tried to plot iteratively but its giving me 'float object unsubscriptable' error.

So can somebody tell me where I am going wrong. Or is there any other method to do this ?

Comment: (len(array1)-1) this excludes every last element do (len(array1))

Comment: test with this: `a='abcde'
>>> for i in range(len(a)-1):
 print(a[i])` - e will be lost

Comment: Ok. co-incidentally my case has only three elements. Even if I give (len(array1)), it is not printing every element.  Also I have used [p+1]. So if I use (len(array1)), it would give index out of range error.

Comment: First `x, y, z, c = zip(*array1)`, next `plt.scatter(x, y, z, c=c, cmap=whatever)` or, using Numpy, `x, y, z, c = array1.T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it by converting your list to array which allows you to slice all the elements directly as x, y, z and color coordinates.

```
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

new_array = = np.array(array1)
ax.scatter(new_array[:,0],new_array[:,1],new_array[:,2], c=new_array[:,3], cmap=cm.RdBu, s=100)
```

[image]

Comment: Hey I got your answer. But since the array is already defined, I tried to use 
    
new_array = np.array([array1])
ax.scatter(array1[:,0],array1[:,1],array1[:,2], c=array1[:,3], cmap=cm.RdBu, s=100)                                                                                                                     

this is giving me the below error -
ValueError: 'c' argument has 1 elements, which is not acceptable for use with 'x' with size 4, 'y' with size 4.

Any way where I need not specify the elements explicitly always when converting list to array.

Comment: You should use new_array=np.array(array1) without the braces [ ]

Comment: Also now you should use the new_array in scatter command. You are still using array1

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot. Converting list to array is the main thing here. But just curious, why can't we work with list as it is ? Because that is how it works or any special reason that you are aware of ?